# How to aggregate floating point array and get precise result with parallelizable method?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, floating-point, aggregate, floating-point-precision

To get the precise sum of a floating point array I just have to sort them and add every pair, then again and add pairs (of those sums of pairs) until I have just one element. (Correct?)

How I do it when I want to find the multiple sum. (correct word?)

I am assuming that multiplying two floating points numbers does: (Is it right too?)

```
// sign -> -1 or 1
// mantissa -> 0.5 ... <1.0 (Never actual 1.0)

new_sign = x_sign * y_sign
new_exponent = x_exponent + y_exponent
new_mantissa = x_mantissa * y_mantissa

if (new_mantissa < 0.5) {
    new_mantissa *= 2.0
    new_exponent--
}
```

There's no precision problem with `new_sign` nor `new_exponent`, I shouldn't give attention to them. I should see precise lose with `new_mantissa`. So should I sort the floating point by their mantissa, and then what? What said is correct?

If I am not in the correct direction, then what is the correct direction to achieve this effect?

Comment: To get as accurate as possible a sum, I would use [Kahan summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm). The code for multiplication is not correct if you are assuming IEEE 754 binary floating point.

Comment: I also don't see why you need to get into the far-more-complicated-than-you-think details of multiplication. What matters is your processor will multiply two numbers producing the closest representable value to their product.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan It isn't paralleizable, or is it? Multiplying too many numbers (billions) will have great error, and I have enough power to even sort those numbers, so why not?

Comment: The main concern I would have with multiplying billions of floating point numbers is exponent overflow or underflow. Sorting would increase the risk of an intermediate result being much larger or smaller than the final product. The one billionth root of the largest finite double is about 1.0000007097829648. The one billionth root of the smallest positive double is about 0.9999992555602052. (Assuming IEEE 754 64 bit binary)

Comment: If there is a risk of overflow or underflow it might be worth while summing the logarithms. Calculating the logarithms is embarrassingly parallelizable. The addition could be sorted or Kahan.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Actually at the end I need to look at the logarithm so it's pretty much solves my problem, but I will let this question be open.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with multiplying billions of doubles is exponent overflow and underflow. Assuming double is IEEE 754 64-bit binary floating point, the one billionth root of the largest finite double is about 1.0000007097829648. The one billionth root of the smallest positive double is about 0.9999992555602052. Multiplying a billion numbers each of which is greater than 1.0000007097829648 will give an infinite results. Multiplying a billion numbers each less than 0.9999992555602052 will underflow to zero.

The simplest solution is to add the logarithms of the inputs to get the logarithm of their product. The logarithms calculation parallelizes extremely well.

For accuracy, the sum of the logarithms should be calculated using [Kahan summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm) to get O(1) error growth. For performance, it should be done in parallel, suggesting [pairwise summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_summation).

It may be worth experimenting with a compromise. Have each processor do Kahan summation of a subset of the inputs, then have one processor do Kahan summation of those sums.

Alternatively, have one thread do a full Kahan summation but feed chunks of logarithms to it as they are generated by all the other threads.

Comment: I am using GPU, it's a bit problemic to run a loop inside GPU, I will try something.